# How to get files from a specific sub-directories using c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get all *.html files which are inside sub-directories named **abcd** to an array.
The path given can contain multiple *.html files in multiple sub-directories and even in the root directory(i.e. immediately inside the user given path) but I only want those *.html files which are inside the specificly named sub-directories(**abcd**) using LINQ.
This is what I tried

```
string workingPath = @"D:\Testing";  
            string[] myFiles = workingPath.Select(dirs => Directory.GetDirectories(workingPath)  
                                           .Select(folders => (from item in Directory.GetDirectories(folders, "abcd", SearchOption.AllDirectories)  
                                                               .Select(item => Directory.GetFiles(item, "*.html"))  
                                                              )));
```

I'm getting an error

> A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause (CS0742)

. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can the subdirectories be nested?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not look like it will compile. To start with `workingPath.Select` will return a collection of chars and you are trying to iterate over that again , which does not make sense considering your requirements.

You need something like this

```
var files = new List<string>();
if (Directory.Exists(workingPath))
{
   foreach (var f in Directory.GetDirectories(workingPath, "abcd",
                                                SearchOption.AllDirectories))
   {
       files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(f, "*.html"));
   }
}
```

You can also do a one liner using LINQ

```
var files2 = Directory.GetDirectories(workingPath, "abcd", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .SelectMany(d => Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.html")).ToArray();
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(f, "*.html"));` instead of `files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.html"));`

Comment: Yes. It is a typo. Was trying to save space, but missed the second line.

Comment: @Shjyu Can this be done in one line of code using LINQ?